# How to solve precision errors in GLES2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, floating-point-precision

I have a map of Brazil composed of about 5000 polygons that each represent it's cities.
Although they share points, they are each their own polygon.

The problem is, that when i draw them all, they form holes in between them, which i assume comes from rounding errors, since these holes disappear/move when zooming/moving the camera.

The problem is even worse when the map is zoomed out.

How do i solve this kind of problem in GLES2.0 (Android)?

Unfortunately i can't enlarge each polygon, and although i could fuse them all into a 'Brazil' polygon and draw it below them, i'd rather avoid doing so since the frame rate is already lower than what i need it to be.

I also tried to add 'precision highp float;' to the start of the shaders, but that didn't change a thing

Two images to illustrate the problem. The first is the zoomed in map, and the other is a zoomed out map, both images are cropped to show only the map

[image: Zoomed in map, still have some issues, but not so glaring] [image: Zoomed out map, very visible flaws]

Comment: This is an issue related to sub-pixel precision in the rasterizer, not the precision of your vertex or fragment shaders. After primitive assembly/clipping and during rasterization points have to be snapped to a grid of positions (window coordinates) and the results of primitive assembly can accumulate FP errors. If you use primitives that share edges (e.g. fans or strips), or draw your polygons to share exactly the same vertex (by index, not position) you stand a better chance of having each polygon rasterize the shared edges properly. However, I think your problem is really very small cities.

Comment: You might want to combine the smaller cities into larger clusters of polygons depending on the scale to avoid this situation. Sort of a level-of-detail system.